# Shopify plugin support for multiple stores

Tags: plugins, localization

With the Shopify plugin, is there a way (or is there a future plan) to support the addition of multiple stores? Thinking about a situation where a client has different Shopify stores for different countries, and would like to serve content from a single, localized base site.

Answer (score 1):

We have looked at this as a possibility, but don’t currently have anything to announce. Our sense is that your situation is pretty common for small- to medium-sized stores, given the cost of Shopify’s localization + multi-market features.

If you would like to see this feature in a future version of the Shopify plugin, please add a discussion to [the repository on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/shopify)! This will help us track requests, centrally.

Thanks for your interest in the plugin! We’re excited to see how it’s used, and where we can improve.

Comment: Thanks August - just added!